# Twitter bootstrap - multiple modal windows

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using the modal window component in a loop. Every loop content has X number of thumbnails with different IDs (the modals also have different IDs) that should trigger the modals by their data-toggle attribute, however the modals only work on the first item of the loop, the data-toggle only set the background of the screen with the rest.
The modal windows contents and markup are in the DOM, only they don't show up.

I have tried removing the fade class, renaming the IDs, but I have no luck so far.
I've found a [similar problem,](http://www.chapter31.com/2011/10/27/twitter-bootstrap-modal-not-working-in-firefox/) but that doesn't help my case.

What could be the problem?

```
<li class="span3">
<div class="modal hide" id="modal1">
   <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
        <h3>Lipsum</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
       <p>Lipsum</p>
   <hr>
   <img src="<?php the_field('srceenshot')?>">
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
       <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
   </div>
</div>
    <a class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" rel="popover" data-content="<?php the_field('screenshot_text')?>" data-original-title="<?php the_field('screenshot_header')?>" href="#modal1">
        <img src="<?php the_field('screenshot')?>">
    </a>
</li>
```

SOLUTION:

```
<div class="modal hide" id="modal1_<?php echo $count">
```

and

```
<a class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" rel="popover" data-content="<?php the_field('screenshot_text')?>" data-original-title="<?php the_field('screenshot_header')?>" href="#modal1_<?php echo $count">
```

Comment: Also make sure the `href` of the button that calls the modal refers to the dynamic ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id=modal1` needs to be dynamic. So it should be something like `id=modal_<PK of Object>`

Comment: well, I don't understand, the content of the modal is dynamic. Are you saying that I should add a dynamically generated suffix the to IDs of the modals?

Comment: Yes try that. Otherwise the modal will only take the last generated object.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I haven't had time to implement it, but you're right: appending a counter to the ID modal1 solves the the problem.

Comment: Glad that was useful! Thanks for coming up to accept the answer!